# Можно ли использовать swagger для документирования не только RESTful API?

Tags: java, spring, swagger

Можно ли использовать Swagger для документирования не только RESTful API, но и других типов API?

Comment: Можете как то конкретизировать вопрос, что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: А зачем? Swagger нужен для внешних интеграций. А для внутренних API есть javadoc.